# Delete items from DynamoDB by type

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with a [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) set on one of the attributes. However when I started ingesting data into the table I accidentally was entering the attribute as a string instead of an integer. This is ignored by the TTL and my records were never being deleted.

After a while I noticed my error and updated the code and the table ceased growing in size as records were being removed as designed. However I still have a few hundred thousand records in the table with the string TTL.

What is the best way for me to delete these records?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a script in python with `boto3` which scans the whole table, gets the keys for items with string TTL attributes and deletes them. However deleting the ~500k items seems to be rather slow. So any other answers would be much appreciated.

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('my-table')

response = table.scan()
data = response['Items']
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    data.extend(response['Items'])

string_keys = [item['key'] for item in data if type(item['ttl']) == str]

with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for key in string_keys:
        batch.delete_item(
            Key={
                'key': key
            },
    )
    string_keys.remove(key)
```

Comment: This is your only way, unless you don't care about any of the data in the table, then just drop an recreate the table. Increase your provisioned write and/or read capacity to make it go faster,